# Open browser window with formed URL after posting a PHP form

Tags: php, javascript, forms

So here's the question. I have this php form that collects some data, after posting the data gets parsed an URL is constructed. After this URL is constructed, I'd like to open a new browser window for the user with this newly constructed URL.

How can I actually accomplish this? Is this something that can only be done with javascript? If so... How?

I already have the code in place and i've tested it works that construct the URL after posting the form, now it's just a matter of opening a new window with the URL.

Comment: Popup blockers might not like that behavior. I'd just echo a hyperlink with target set appropriately.

Comment: I agree with @Novikov. Opening a new window will annoy your users. Why not perform a redirect using `header`? Also, what is the purpose of the new window?

Comment: The client requirements are that a new window comes up because it's a total redirect. I'd offer a hyperlink as an alternative but the popup must come up. Also, is there a way I can replace the current page after posting the form? As in redirecting in the same window to the new URL.

Comment: I've tried using header, but it gives me an error that a header is already set. The client requirements are that the form uses this new page with parameters through get that's why after parsing the form data, I construct the URL to redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send the *current* window to that URL with an HTTP header:

```
<?php
//your code that builds $url
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

If you must open a second, new window, then you must use JavaScript.

Comment: This is the error i ge whenever i try that: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: You can't have any output before sending HTTP headers. If you want to redirect, you can't echo anything, including whitespace characters before the `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some example HTML including inline JS ([try it](http://jsfiddle.net/S9BfK/4/)). We need to open a new window when the form is submitted to avoid the browser's pop-up blocker:

```
<form
    method="POST"
    action="http://www.cs.tut.fi/cgi-bin/run/~jkorpela/echo.cgi"
    onsubmit="open('',this.target=new Date().getTime(),'menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=600')">
    <!-- Text boxes, etc. go here --->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In your PHP script, you could use (with no whitespace or other characters before it):

```
<?php

// Your code that determines the URL; don't send any output from it!

header("Location: $url");
```

Failing that, you could use this PHP/JavaScript code to achieve a similar effect:

```
<script>
    location.replace("<?php echo $url; ?>");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Js window.open ("http://www.newurl.com","mywindow"); for more details check this link http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Comment: I've tried using this through the php script with no luck, would you  mind posting a PHP example of an implementation?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function newWindow() {

    window.open("http://www.newurl.com", "", "width=400,height=500,top=50,left=280,
    resizable,toolbar,scrollbars,menubar,");
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type=submit  name="submit" value="Preview" onClick="newWindow();">  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open new window using php in same session only javascript are capable to do that, there can be two scenarios

1. using AJAX request
2. Reload a page and initialise a javascript